# Is a space always homeomorphic to the disjoint union of a disjoint cover?

Tags: general-topology

If $X$ is a topological space and $X_{\alpha}$ is a pairwise disjoint cover of $X$ (for example the connected components), then are $\bigsqcup_{\alpha}X_{\alpha}$, with the usual sum topology, and $X$ always homeomorphic under the natural map $(x,\alpha) \mapsto x$?

It seems to me like this should always be true, as the union and disjoint union don't really seem to do anything different aside from an extra label involving $\alpha$. However, I can only prove it true when all components $X_{\alpha}$ are open.

This question arose for me in the context of locally connected spaces. In the lecture notes I am following it says, "Every space we consider in this course can be written as $ X = \bigsqcup_{\alpha \in \pi_0(X)} X_{\alpha}$, with $X$ connected, and has a continuous function $X \to \pi_0(X)$ where $\pi_0(X)$ has the discrete topology." It seemed to me that he was identifying $X$ and $\bigsqcup_{\alpha \in \pi_0(X)} X_{\alpha}$ (using the natural map above). Just to check my sanity, isn't this statement always true when viewed as $\bigsqcup_{\alpha \in \pi_0(X)} X_{\alpha} \to \pi_0(X)$ since $\pi_0^{-1}(\{\alpha\}) = X_{\alpha} \times \{\alpha\}$ is always (cl)open? Help would be appreciated!

Comment: To answer your first question, think of your favorite non-Hausdorff space $X$ and the collection $\{\{x\} : x\in X\}$. Is $X$ homeomorphic to the topological sum of the family $\{\{x\} : x\in X\}$?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Yes, I see what you mean. I got a bit caught in the weeds.

Comment: @Peluso Thanks for the example, just to verify I am thinking about this right, the topological sum you described is always endowed with the discrete topology and is hence Hausdorff?

Comment: That's right. Another example of the sort is to consider your favorite connected space $Y$ and the corresponding cover $\{\{y\} : y\in Y\}$. The sum is not connected but $Y$ is. In short, you do have to be careful with the topological sum. As you mention, in the case where each element of the cover is open, it does happen that the original space is homeomorphic to the topological sum, but that is a very special situation.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! Now I feel a lot better about this, it was bugging me for a bit there

Comment: As another example $\Bbb Q$ is not homeomorphic to the disjoint sum of his components, as you observed they need to be open